# Rotating triangle & changing its color in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm new to openGL, I need help with animate a triangle that rotates 1 degree every 25 milliseconds. I want to program this triangle to gradually change color from blue to green to red.

```
float rAngle=0.0;

void handleResize(int w,int h)
{
   glViewport(0,0,w,h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective(45.0,(double)w/(double)h,1.0,200.0);
}

void drawscene()
{
   glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glRotatef(-rAngle,0.0f,0.0f,0.1f);
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   glVertex3f(-0.5f,0.5f,-5.0f);
   glVertex3f(-1.0f,1.5f,-5.0f);
   glVertex3f(-1.5f,0.5f,-5.0f);
   glEnd();
   glFlush();
}
void update(int value)
{
    rAngle+=1.0f;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(25,update,0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");
    glutDisplayFunc(drawscene);
    glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
    glutTimerFunc(25,update,0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?Also, you should learn modern OpenGL that is using shaders.

Answer (score 2):

**This way of using OpenGL is deprecated.**

Let me start off by pointing out that there is no reason to dabble with old outdated OpenGL. Immediate mode has been deprecated for about 10 years now.

Learn [modern OpenGL](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/) instead.

Although the question is very unclear, I will try to give you the info you need.

**Push/Pop Matrix:**

[glPushMatrix()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml):

> There is a stack of matrices for each of the matrix modes. In GL_MODELVIEW mode, the stack depth is at least 32. In the other modes, GL_COLOR, GL_PROJECTION, and GL_TEXTURE, the depth is at least 2. The current matrix in any mode is the matrix on the top of the stack for that mode.
>
> glPushMatrix pushes the current matrix stack down by one, duplicating the current matrix. That is, after a glPushMatrix call, the matrix on top of the stack is identical to the one below it.
>
> glPopMatrix pops the current matrix stack, replacing the current matrix with the one below it on the stack.
>
> Initially, each of the stacks contains one matrix, an identity matrix.

**Rotation:**

To rotate the current matrix, call [glRotate()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml).

**Color:**

Use [these](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColor.xml) to select rendering color.

Usually, `glColor3f()` or `glColor4f()` is used.

**Your scenario:**

1. Call `glColor3f()` or `glColor4f()` to select rendering color.
2. Call `glPushMatrix()` to avoid rotating everything.
3. Call `glRotate()` to rotate the matrix.
4. Render mesh.
5. Call `glPopMatrix()` to revert out of the rotated matrix.

**To modify per time unit:**

Just modify the data sent into the GL functions over time. Increase the rotation/color values a bit each frame.

**I suggest reading up on matrix math, and how graphics incorporates this.**